# Show that the expected value of $X$ is equal to $E(x)$

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables, expected-value

> Consider a random variable $X : Ω → \{1, . . . , 15\}$, that takes on integer values in the set $\{1, . . . , 15\}$. Show that the expected value of $X$ is equal to: $$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{15} P(X ≥ i)$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X)&=& \sum_{k=1}^{15}k \cdot \mathbb P\{X=k\}\\
 &=& \color{red}{\mathbb P\{X=1\}}\\
&+& \color{red}{\mathbb P\{X=2\}}+ \color{blue}{\mathbb P\{X=2\}}\\
&+& \color{red}{\mathbb P\{X=3\}}+ \color{blue}{\mathbb P\{X=3\}}+ \color{green}{\mathbb P\{X=3\}}\\
& \vdots &\\
&+& \color{red}{\mathbb P\{X=15\}}+ \color{blue}{\mathbb P\{X=15\}}+ \color{green}{\mathbb P\{X=15\}}+\dots + \mathbb P\{X=15\}\\
&=& \color{red}{\mathbb P\{X\geq 1\}}+ \color{blue}{\mathbb P\{X\geq 2\}}+ \color{green}{\mathbb P\{X\geq 3\}}+\dots + \mathbb P\{X=15\}\\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{15} \mathbb P\{X\geq k\}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{X\geq i\}=\sum_{k=i}^{15}\mathbb P\{X=k\}.$$